# Как создать и заполнить массив экземплярами класса?

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, sfml

Я программирую на c++ и использую графическую библиотеку SFML.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

class Ball //Класс шара
{
public:
    Ball(double radius, Color color, double x, double y, double dx, double dy) //dy и dx - направления шара
    {
        this->radius = radius;
        this->color = color;
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->dx = dx;
        this->dy = dy;
    }

    void draw(RenderWindow& window, CircleShape& shape) //Рисуем шар
    {
        shape.setFillColor(this->color);
        shape.setRadius(this->radius);
        shape.setOrigin(this->radius, this->radius);
        shape.setPosition(this->x, this->y);
        window.draw(shape);
    }

    void move(int winSize) //Двигаем шар
    {
        this->x += this->dx;
        this->y += this->dy;

        if (this->y < this->radius)
        {
            this->dy = -this->dy;
            this->y = this->radius;
        }
        else if (this->y > winSize - this->radius)
        {
            this->dy = -this->dy;
            this->y = winSize - this->radius;
        }

        if (this->x < this->radius)
        {
            this->dx = -this->dx;
            this->x = this->radius;
        }
        else if (this->x > winSize - this->radius)
        {
            this->dx = -this->dx;
            this->x = winSize - this->radius;
        }
    }

    void update(RenderWindow& window, CircleShape& shape, int winSize) //Сначала двигаем шар, а потом рисуем
    {
        this->move(winSize);
        this->draw(window, shape);
    }

private:
    double radius;
    Color color;
    double y;
    double x;
    double dy;
    double dx;
};

int main()
{
    const int winSize = 900;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(winSize, winSize), "Ball"); //Окно
    CircleShape shape(0);
    Ball ball(30, Color(255, 255, 0), 300, 450, 3, 2); //Шар

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) //Проверка событий
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        ball.update(window, shape, winSize); //Двигаем и рисуем шар
        window.display();
    }
}
```

В `Ball ball(30, Color(255, 255, 0), 300, 450, 3, 2);` создаётся шар и с помощью `ball.update(window, shape, winSize);` двигается и выводится на экран. Но что делать, если я хочу создать больше шаров, например 100? Можно создать массив `balls`, указать его размер в `const int numberOfBalls` и заполнить его шарами, а потом `ball.update(window, shape, winSize);` заменить на

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBalls; i++)
    {
        balls[i].update(window, shape, winSize);
    }
```

вызывая у каждого шара функцию `update()`. Но у меня не получается заполнить массив шарами. Я попробовал создать и заполнить массив шарами так

```
const int numberOfBalls = 100;
Ball balls[numberOfBalls];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBalls; i++)
{
    balls[i] = ball(30, Color(255, 255, 0), 300, 450, 3, 2);
}
```

Но visual studio говорит, что есть 2 ошибки. Первая в `Ball balls[numberOfBalls];`, что нету конструктора по умолчанию, а вторая в `balls[i] = ball(30, Color(255, 255, 0), 300, 450, 3, 2);`, что идентификатор `ball` не определён.

Comment: Вторая ошибка - потому что название класса пишется с большой буквы.

Comment: А первая - определите в классе конструктор без параметров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не принципиально использовать именно массив, советую `std::vector`. С его использованием можно преобразовать Ваш код так:

```cpp
#include <vector>
//...
//...
//...
const int numberOfBalls = 100;
std::vector<Ball> balls;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBalls; i++)
{
    // Обратите внимание, как уже заметили в комментариях, имя класса с заглавной буквы
    balls.push_back(Ball(30, Color(255, 255, 0), 300, 450, 3, 2));
}
```

Дальше к элементам вектора можно обращаться так же, как к элементам обычного массива:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBalls; i++)
{
    balls[i].update(window, shape, winSize);
}
```

А можно и ещё удобнее, но здесь уже читайте про [вектор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(C%2B%2B))